# Get text length in characters number Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a text box (EditText) where I will insert text, and a button that should calculate the lentgh of that text and display it in the another text box. How should I code that button?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1=findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button b2=findViewById(R.id.b2);
    EditText t1=findViewById(R.id.t1);
    TextView t2;
    t2 = findViewById(R.id.t2);


    b1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        int nb=0;
        for(int i=0; i<t1.length(); ++i){
            nb++;
        }
        t2.setText(Integer.toString(nb));
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        t2.setText(t1.getText().toString());
    });
}
```

Comment: You can simply use t2.setText(Integer.toString(t1.getText().length()));

Comment: You already have an answer so why do you put the question? @coderGirl

Comment: hey @MohakShah i found the solution after i posed the question, so i taught i'd keep the question and share the result for others, Thank you for you're input .